# Use bnd tools to generate MANIFEST files

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bndtools

I just knew about the existence of this tool (bnd tools), which seems perfect to solve the issue I'm having in an OSGI application that I am developing.I've been reading some documentation about it, but I must be doing something wrong.

I had a problem in the aforementioned application, on a bundle which I've been unable to activate ([OSGI bundle is unable to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406759/osgi-bundle-is-unable-to-start)), and by following other user's advices in my previous post, I decided to try to use bnd tools to solve it. In my project's folder, I created a new Run Descriptor (New > Run Descriptor) and after naming it 'run', I chose Apache Felix 4 with Gogo Shell before clicking Finish.

Now, when I open the run.bndrun file, I got these 2 error mesages:

> Repository List: Unable to load OSGI Repositories. No workspace found
>   from: /home/user/proj/sm/workspace OSGI framework: Unable to load OSGI framework
>   list. No workspace found from: /home/user/proj/sm/workspace

This file's content is the following:

```
-runfw: org.apache.felix.framework;version='[4,5)'
-runee: JavaSE-1.6
-runsystemcapabilities: ${native_capability}

-resolve.effective: active

-runbundles:\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.command

-runrequires:\
    osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.shell)',\
    osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.command)'
```

How can I solve these two errors? Can I use bnd tools the way I want to use it?

Comment: Sorry rsy, this it sounds like this might not be helpful for you... But for people who stumbled here googling the error after faffing around with their repositories etc., restarting eclipse sorted it out easily enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the **exact** error messages. It looks like you have a setup error. bnd tries to find your setup relative to your project. This should not be possible if you just apply the defaults though. Your workspace on the file system should look like:

```
cnf/
  build.bnd
  ..
my.project
  src/
  bin/
  test/
  bin_test/
  ...
```

Comment: Initial post edited, also with the file's contents. The generated file looks quite different than yours, I really don't know how to edit it...